# Tell smartphone browser to use actual resolution to CSS media query

Tags: android, media-queries

I have a website for my bookmarks that works well on all resolutions with CSS media queries. If I scale down my Firefox window, it works just fine:

http://wstaw.org/m/2013/03/21/Bookmarks_-_Mozilla_Firefox_001.png

http://wstaw.org/m/2013/03/21/Bookmarks_-_Mozilla_Firefox_002.png

However, on my Android 4.0 phone with the stock browser, it displays a much wider version of the site, but scaled down. It is pretty unusable that way:

http://wstaw.org/m/2013/03/21/Screenshot_2013-03-21-13-36-57.png

Is there a way to tell the browser to use the actual device resolution for the media query and not some resolution it made up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tag should help you:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5">
```

Where:

initial-scale=x - set scale to x during open

maximum-scale=y - allow zoom max y times